# PHP -> function calls break page

Tags: php, apache, apache2, mysql

I've been trying to setup a login page with PHP and MySQL, and I'm running into an issue when I use prepared statements with the -> operator. I have php5 and apache2 installed correctly, and `phpinfo();` runs with no problem, but when I use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
            <br />
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <br />
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <?php 
            error_reporting(-1);
            ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

            if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
                $logged_in = false;

                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];

                $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'db');

                /* create a prepared statement */
                if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, password, salt FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?")) {

                    /* bind parameters for markers */
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

                    /* execute query */
                    $stmt->execute();

                    $stmt->bind_result($storedUser, $storedPassword, $storedSalt);

                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                        // $storedUser, $storedPassword, $storedSalt
                        if (crypt($password, $storedSalt) == $storedPassword) {
                            $logged_in = true;
                        }
                    }

                    /* close statement */
                    $stmt->close();

                    if ($logged_in === true) {
                        echo 'Successfully logged in as ' . $username;
                    }
                }
            }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

the php breaks at the > and the rest is displayed to the page.

```
prepare("SELECT username, password, salt FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?")) { /* bind parameters for markers */ $stmt->bind_param("s", $username); /* execute query */ $stmt->execute(); $stmt->bind_result($storedUser, $storedPassword, $storedSalt); while ($stmt->fetch()) { // $storedUser, $storedPassword, $storedSalt if (crypt($password, $storedSalt) == $storedPassword) { $logged_in = true; } } /* close statement */ $stmt->close(); if ($logged_in === true) { echo 'Successfully logged in as ' . $username; } } } ?>
```

Comment: what is the error or warning you are getting ?

Comment: @thepiyush13 No errors are shown when I use `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`, is there any other place I would be able to see them?

Comment: can you please post your complete code? it is not quite clear what the issue could be

Comment: @thepiyush13 I just added the full code.

Comment: ok thanks, few things first  1) verify the query by directly running in sql server that it works 2) try to check if $conn is valid by printing it`s value

Comment: @thepiyush13 I don't think the problem is directly related to my code, which is why I originally posted on webmasters.stackexchange.com before it was migrated for some reason. I can connect to the sql server without problem. I will check `$conn` in a minute

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` work when used in this document?

Comment: @w3d As I said in my original post, it does.

Comment: Well, you stated that `phpinfo()` runs, you didn't state where you were running it. The output you were getting is consistent with the file not being processed by PHP. The `>` is seen as a closing tag delimiter.

Comment: @w3d Yes, I see that I was not clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm still not sure what caused this issue, I fixed it by running:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 php5
sudo apt-get remove --purge libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install php5 apache2 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

Thank you everyone for all of your help.